# Compare Dictionary key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

is there any way in python to compare a key and value in the same dictionary??

```
{A[0]: u , u: A[3]}
```

can I compare the value of A[0] to u (key)??

Comment: Please explain what you ultimately trying to archive with this. Also please give some better example code, that does not use undefined variables.

Comment: I basically want to replace the value of u that is A[3] into the value of A[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a dictionary keys by calling `<dictionary_name>.keys()` and over the values by calling `<dictionary_name>.values()`. So, if I have understood your question correctly, below is what you want to do:

```
a = {'A': 'u', 'u': 3} 
for key in a.keys():
   for val in a.values():
      if key == val:
         print key # or whatever you want to do with it after comparing
```